# Change the upload on date API V3 youtube

Tags: .net, youtube-api

I'm using youtube API to insert old videos that I have from amazon,

And it works like a charm but I would like to know if it's possible to change the upload on date, because I'm setting the publishedAt parameter inside the snippet but I have not seen any way to change the upload on date  -,-

Maybe there is no choice for that -.-'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible with Youtube currently. Nothing to do with .net API (I frankly have no idea), but I recently created a Youtube channel and was trying the same thing. i.e. I have 30 odd interview videos and I posted the latest ones first, then tried to add older videos, but sorting always happens by upload date.

So I went and tried to do a bit of search to see if I could change the upload date, but that doesn't seem possible at the moment

There was one post that said you could unpublish and republish videos to reset the upload date, but that no longer seems to be working

See links for validity of my statement:

https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/youtube/OzbQIe0YmQ0
https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/youtube-creator-academy/4dFeX1vqmi4

https://www.reddit.com/r/NoStupidQuestions/comments/369g7o/how_do_you_change_the_upload_date_on_youtube/ -- this says you can reset it, but as of this moment, it's not working